# How to group dictionaries based on two values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, group-by

How to group list of dictionaries as list of unique dictionaries based on multiple key elements?

```
in = [{'location': 'eastus', 'sku': 'S', 'term': 'P1', 'scope': '1'},
         {'location': 'india', 'sku': 'a', 'term': 'P1', 'scope': '2'},
         {'location': 'eastus', 'sku': 'S', 'term': 'P3', 'scope': '3'},
         {'location': 'india', 'sku': 'f', 'term': 'P1', 'scope': '4'},
         {'location': 'japan', 'sku': 'a', 'term': 'P1', 'scope': '5'},
         {'location': 'india', 'sku': 'a', 'term': 'P3', 'scope': '6'}
      ]
```

**The key elements are 'location' and 'sku'.** I want to group dictionaries having same key elements into a single dict, where the rest of the keys having different value will go into a list of separate dictionaries inside that same dict.

Expected output:

```
out = [{'location': 'eastus', 'sku': 'S', 'new_key': [
                                                     {'term': 'P1', 'scope': '1'}, 
                                                     {'term': 'P3', 'scope': '3'}
                                                    ]},
           {'location': 'india', 'sku': 'a', 'new_key': [
                                                     {'term': 'P1', 'scope': '2'},
                                                     {'term': 'P3', 'scope': '6'}
                                                    ]},
           {'location': 'india', 'sku': 'f', 'term': 'P1', 'scope': '4'},
           {'location': 'japan', 'sku': 'a', 'term': 'P1', 'scope': '5'},
        ]
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53983695/group-list-of-dictionary-as-list-of-list-of-dictionary-based-on-multiple-keys) with required modifications but do we have a better and more accurate solution?

Comment: What do you mean "better and more accurate"?

Comment: If your code is working, I'd suggest you post it on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), that's the place for it.

Comment: It looks like you are processing a list of dictionnaries sharing same keys. Pandas does a great job with this kind of data, indexing, search, vectorized (high performance) operations on columns...

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [{'location': 'eastus', 'sku': 'S', 'term': 'P1', 'scope': '1'},
         {'location': 'india', 'sku': 'a', 'term': 'P1', 'scope': '2'},
         {'location': 'eastus', 'sku': 'S', 'term': 'P3', 'scope': '3'},
         {'location': 'india', 'sku': 'f', 'term': 'P1', 'scope': '4'},
         {'location': 'japan', 'sku': 'a', 'term': 'P1', 'scope': '5'},
         {'location': 'india', 'sku': 'a', 'term': 'P3', 'scope': '6'}
      ]
result = []
for k, v in groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x: (x["location"], x["sku"])), lambda x: (x["location"], x["sku"])):
    temp = dict(zip(('location', 'sku'), k))
    sub_value = list(v)
    if len(sub_value) == 1:
        temp.update(sub_value[0])
    else:
        temp.update({'new_key': sub_value})
    result.append(temp)

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'location': 'eastus',
  'new_key': [{'location': 'eastus', 'scope': '1', 'sku': 'S', 'term': 'P1'},
              {'location': 'eastus', 'scope': '3', 'sku': 'S', 'term': 'P3'}],
  'sku': 'S'},
 {'location': 'india',
  'new_key': [{'location': 'india', 'scope': '2', 'sku': 'a', 'term': 'P1'},
              {'location': 'india', 'scope': '6', 'sku': 'a', 'term': 'P3'}],
  'sku': 'a'},
 {'location': 'india', 'scope': '4', 'sku': 'f', 'term': 'P1'},
 {'location': 'japan', 'scope': '5', 'sku': 'a', 'term': 'P1'}]
```

Comment: I don`t need all the key-value pair inside the nested list with key as 'new_key'. I just want the key-value pairs which are left out. 

See, my expected output @rakesh

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with nested list comprehensions and some nasty lambdas too:

```
from itertools import groupby
import pprint

pp=pprint.PrettyPrinter()

data = [{'location': 'eastus', 'sku': 'S', 'term': 'P1', 'scope': '1'},
         {'location': 'india', 'sku': 'a', 'term': 'P1', 'scope': '2'},
         {'location': 'eastus', 'sku': 'S', 'term': 'P3', 'scope': '3'},
         {'location': 'india', 'sku': 'f', 'term': 'P1', 'scope': '4'},
         {'location': 'japan', 'sku': 'a', 'term': 'P1', 'scope': '5'},
         {'location': 'india', 'sku': 'a', 'term': 'P3', 'scope': '6'}]

pp.pprint([(lambda k,g:k.update({"new_key":[(lambda i:i.pop("location") and i.pop("sku") and i)(item) for item in g]}) or k)(k,g) for k,g in groupby(sorted(data,key=lambda i:(i["location"],i["sku"])), lambda i:{"location":i["location"],"sku":i["sku"]})])
```

Test is here: https://ideone.com/24bjKw. However this one destroys the original `data` in the process (the `i.pop()` calls work on the original dicts).

The chaining of steps in the inner lambdas are the only tricky parts:

```
lambda i:i.pop("location") and i.pop("sku") and i
```

uses `and`, because `pop` returns what it found, so this way short-circuit evaluation can not interfere and `i` is going to be the actual value of the expression. (If there would be a doubt about `pop()` finding the keys, it could be `i.pop("...",True)`)

```
lambda k,g:k.update(...) or k
```

needs an `or` because `update()` returns `None` (and thus an `and` would short-circuit here).

The rest is just typing. Unfortunately I have no good idea about formatting it into a nicer shape.

Answer (score 0):

**I have modified the above answer and it gives me the expected output.** By the way, thanks @rakesh

```
    from itertools import groupby
    result = []
    keys = ('location', 'sku')
    for k, v in groupby(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (x["location"], x["sku"])), lambda x: (x["location"], x["sku"])):
        temp = dict(zip(keys, k))
        sub_value = list(v)
        if len(sub_value) == 1:
            temp.update({'new_key': sub_value[0]})
            list(map(temp['new_key'].pop, keys))
        else:
            temp.update({'new_key': sub_value})
            for i in temp['new_key']:
                list(map(i.pop, keys))
        result.append(temp)
    print(result)
```